# What is the best practice to define height of sections in web page with padding vs height( usingvh) vs min-height

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I am beginner at web development and would like to ask you about the best practice to define height of sections in web page. As I was watching html & css tutorial an author used padding to give height to a section but I was wondering isn't it better to define height with height attribute with vh unit or something like that or should I use min-height. Due to confusion faced I decided to ask from you. I really hope for your help.

Comment: Go read tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for me it's more safer to adjust the section's height through padding. One reason is that when you set a specific height for the section it is not responsive enough to adjust as the screen sizes decrease. For height using vh that makes the section occupy the width and height of the monitor screen, but still you have to unset that when you are making the page responsive. For the min-height you can use that for service boxes or two columns that should be in equal height.  :)